# Python pandas множественный фильтр только по True условиям

Tags: python, pandas

Необходимо отфильтровать DataFrame по множесву фильтров. Но требуется чтобы филтр применялся только если условие фильтра выполняется.

Как есть:

```
frame = pd.DataFrame({"col_one": [1,2],
                      "col_two": [3,4]})

test_filter = frame[(frame["col_one"] == 1) &
                    (frame["col_two"] == 5)]

print(len(test_filter))
# Out 0
```

Хочется как то так:

```
frame = frame[(if 1 in listframe["col_one"]: frame["col_one"] == 1) &
               (if 5 in frame["col_two"]: frame["col_two"] == 5)]

print(len(frame))
# Out 1
```

Просьба подсказать решение.

Comment: Фильтр всегда применяется только если его условие выполняется. Ваш вопрос не ясен. особенно желаемое поведение. опишите словами алгоритм хотя бы.

Comment: поменяйте `&` на `|`

Comment: Фильтрую фрейм из 200к строк по >10 столбцам(условиям), условие вхождение значения каждого столбца в столбцы другого фрейма на 100к строк.  Если любое из 10 условий не выполняется получаю пустой фрейм. Хочу чтобы было так: прошёл фильтр 1, если получилось больше 0 строк, применяю фильр 2, и т.д. Если на каком либо фильре получаю 0, тогда результат этого фильтра не учитываю и применяю следуюшщий фильтр.

Comment: #splash58.  Или  мне не подходит. Желаему логику описал чуть выше.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понял ваши комментарии, то можно сделать через `query`:

```
import pandas as pd

frame = pd.DataFrame({"col_one": [1,2],
                      "col_two": [3,4]})

filters = [
    "col_one == 1",
    "col_two == 5",
]

result = frame
for f in filters:
    tmp = result.query(f)
    if tmp.size > 0:
        result = tmp
print(result)
```

Вывод:

```
   col_one  col_two
0        1        3
```

Comment: Тоже задумывался о цикле, но думал может в пандасе есть интегрированный инструмент.

Comment: С такой хитрой логикой - вряд ли. Вам же последовательно нужно проверять, так что только цикл

Comment: Элегантное решение. Спасибо!